# How to get rid of animated value or "purple value"

Tags: animation, keyframes

I animated an object location with #frames, now I want to delete it, how?

[image]

Comment: purple is not for keyframes, it's for drivers, right click on the value and Delete Drivers

Answer (score 1):

Purple is not for keyframes, it's for drivers, right click on the value and *Delete Drivers*. As for the keyframe, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>.

Comment: uhm...äh...but without drivers you don't get packages, no taxis...no uber....you shouldn't "delete" drivers...that's kind of unkind....

Comment: Who needs a driver with a Tesla?

Comment: in europe everybody because fully self driving is not allowed here :( will change in 2047...that's why "good old" Europe loses more and more market shares in every market because they kill themselfes with rules....‍♂️

Comment: don't tell me that your jesusmobile doesn't have autopilot  :/

Comment: actually i am the jesusmobile because "christoph"  -> wikipedia: His most famous legend tells that he carried a child, who was unknown to him, across a river before the child revealed himself as Christ.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Christopher